# SQL server: concatenating values from two numeric columns

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008. I have made a new numeric column called `unique_number` and I would like to populate this column by concatenating two other numeric columns called `site` and `number`.  The `site` column ranges from 1-31 and the values smaller than 10 do not have a zero in front of them.  I Would like the following

```
Number      Site   unique_number
1234567      2       12345672
3456789      26      345678926
```

Using the `+` I have been able to get `unique_number` to be the sum of the two columns, but I want a concatenation to occur, not a summation. I've tried other suggestions using cast as `varchar`, but the select statement continues to give me errors.  Is there a reasonable way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need to store this? Does `Number` always have 7 digits (and if not how will you know if `12345622` is `123456,22` or `1234562,2`)

Answer (score 11):

You should be able to cast both of the columns as a `varchar` and then concatenate them:

```
select number, site, 
  cast(number as varchar(50)) 
  + cast(site as varchar(2)) unique_number
from yt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7116c/2)

If you want to update your table, then you would just use the above in an update statement:

```
update yt
set unique_number = cast(cast(number as varchar(50)) 
                          + cast(site as varchar(2)) as int);
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b51d2)

Comment: That was easy, thanks. Any clue about how to update my table at the same time? When I use the update statement errors occur because of the select statement

Comment: @user2448666 you will just use an UPDATE statement, see my edit with demo

Comment: I had to change int to numeric, but this worked perfectly. Thanks for the help.